# CSS Background Image not displaying within Django framework

Tags: html, css, django, background-image

Following the Polls Webapp tutorial in Django. Keep receiving a 404 error through my command line and my image icon is displayed, but not the image itself.

Tried changing the path a couple times, resetting the static migration, and changing my static root. Still no image.

Here is my style.css

```
li a {
    color: green;
}

body {
    background-image: url('static/images/background.png') no-repeat;
}
```

Here is my index.html

```
{% if latest_question_list %}
    <ul>
        {% for question in latest_question_list %}
        <li><a href="{% url 'polls:detail' question.id %}">{{ question.question_text }}</a>
        </li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
{% else %}
    <p>No polls are available.</p>
{% endif %}

{% load static %}

<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'polls/style.css' %}">

<img src="{% static 'static/images/background.png' %}" alt="My Image">
```

Here is some of my settings.py

```
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'


MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
```

Anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. It's better to add :link and/or :visited to the selector (anchor tag)
2. Add forward slash (/) to the beginning of the `url` value of the property `background-image`.

```
li a:link,
li a:visited {
    color: green;
}

body {
    background-image: url('/static/images/background.png') no-repeat;
}
```

3. remove `static/` from the `img` src.

```
{% load static %}

<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'polls/style.css' %}">

<img src="{% static 'images/background.png' %}" alt="My Image">

{% if latest_question_list %}
    <ul>
        {% for question in latest_question_list %}
        <li><a href="{% url 'polls:detail' question.id %}">{{ question.question_text }}</a>
        </li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
{% else %}
    <p>No polls are available.</p>
{% endif %}
```

4. Remove forward slash (/) from `STATIC_URL` and add `STATICFILES_DIRS` in `settings.py`

`settings.py`:

```
STATIC_URL = 'static/'

MEDIA_URL = '/images/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
]

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static/images')
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
```

5. Make sure you updated `urlpatterns` in `urls.py`

`<project_name>/urls.py`:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    ...
]

urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

Comment: This worked, Thank you so much! I also needed to move the image folder into the static, didn't realize I had it in the polls directory.